# Hilbert's irreducibility theorem and thin sets from Serre's Topics in Galois Theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory

In $\S3.3$: **Irreducibility theorem and thin sets** from Serre's Topics in Galois theory, he states the following:

> Let $\pi: W\to V$ be a Galois covering with Galois group $G$, where $V,W$ denote $K$-irreducible varieties, $V=W/G$, and $G$ acts faithfully on $W$. Let us say that $P\in V(K)$ has property $\operatorname{Irr}(P)$ if $P$ is ``inert", i.e. the inverse image of $P$ (in the scheme sense) is one point, i.e. the affine ring of the fiber is a field $K_P$ (or, equivalently, $G_K$ acts freely and transitively on the $\overline{K}$-points of $W$ above $P$). In this case, $\pi$ is étale above $P$ and the field $K_P$ is a Galois extension of $K$ with Galois group $G$.

I believe here $K$ arises as the residue field of $P$. But what if $P\in V(K)$ happens to be such that $P\in V(F)$ where $F\subset K$ is a proper subfield? Then, wouldn't the residue field at $P$ be a proper subfield of $K$?

Comment: If $K$-irreducible means that the varieties are defined over $K$, then no, because the residue field of any point of a $K$-scheme is an extension of $K$. (What's Serre's definition of $K$-irreducible here?)

Comment: I believe $V,W$ are defined over $K$, so the situation arising in my question would never happen. Thanks for the comment, it makes sense now.